# Better ListView C# - Handling column sorting event

Tags: c#, better-listview

I have inherited a C# project that uses `BetterListView` and I cannot find any good examples of it's usage anywhere. I want to use the `BetterListViewColumnHeaderStyle.Sortable` property in conjunction with a custom comparer to sort `SubItems` in numeric value columns.

As it stands, I can currently sort by the  view using a column index that I specify on instantiation but I cannot find an event method that I can override to get the column index and sorting order to pass to the comparer.

Thanks.

Comment: Been through that. It is in close competition with my own code commentary. Woeful documentation!

Comment: [`BetterListView.ItemComparer`](http://www.componentowl.com/documentation/better-listview/data/chapter-sort.html) maybe?

Comment: Using it already. I need to get the column index that needs sorting through the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below on instantiation:

```
ColumnClicked += new BetterListViewColumnClickedEventHandler(OnColumnClicked);
```

Then add handler code below:

```
private void OnColumnClicked(object sender, BetterListViewColumnClickedEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
    Sorter.SortColumn = eventArgs.ColumnHeader.Index;
    Sorter.Order = eventArgs.ColumnHeader.SortOrder;
  }
```